# Git add -A from shell script

Tags: php, git, bash

After a lot of searching, I'm about to tear my hair out on this one and solution might even be dead simple but I've just overlooked it...

I'm trying run a shell script from PHP to `git add -A` and commit everything in the repository when a button on a web UI is clicked.

```php
<? php
$commitMsg = 'foo';
$output = shell_exec('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gitlist/bash/gitlist-commit '.$commitMsg);
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/development
sudo -H -u username git add -A
sudo -H -u username git commit -m $1
```

It works on my MAMP/OSX setup, but not on my Ubuntu LTS box. What might I have overlooked?

On the server, I get returned, which I'm guessing means that the `git add -A` command is just not working. Am I right?

It also works when running directly from the terminal, but not when running via the web UI.

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified: README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you sure the executing user has sudoers?

Comment: Re: "on the server i get returned": Did you leave out a few words here?

Comment: Please use capitalization and punctuation correctly; Stack-Overflow users will be more likely to take the time to read and answer your questions.

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x script_name.sh`, maybe you'll spot the error right away.

Comment: I just mean when I echo $output thats the message I get.

@Jubobs can you please tell me what is wrong with my question? It looks like a pretty straight forward question to me.

Comment: @digital-pollution The content may be OK, but the form wasn't. Have a look at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27930504/revisions) to see what was improved. The better your question reads, the more chances you have to get potential answerers to eyeball it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ShellFish - the script works perfect in the terminal just not when being executed by phps shell_exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git add .; git add -u` as this will accomplish the same thing "adding all files" but is a potential workaround based on your shell setup.

Comment: oh man you are my hero. this worked great, I'd love to know why if you get a moment. Thank you again!

Comment: @digital-pollution sure thing 
[git add -A stages All]
[git add . stages new and modified, without deleted]
[git add -u stages modified and deleted, without new]

Comment: oh thanks I meant, what could it be about my shell setup that requires this workaround I have the same problem with pushing and pulling